# LINQ, handle Null in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Im trying to pass AverageRating to my view. AverageRating is the result of querying items in an Icollection of Review Model. Review Model has a property of Rating. However i get this message:

> > System.ArgumentNullException

This happens whenever the get is performed, which is understandable. However how do i best handle null exceptions in my model or elsewhere when my code looks like the following:

```
public class MyModel
{

        //Querying this navigation property
        public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

        public double? AverageRating
        {
        get
        { 
            //check that this is not null / handle null
            return Math.Round(Reviews.Average(c => c.Rating), 1);
        }

        }

}
```

```
public class Review
{
    [Key]
    public int ReviewID { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int CoachID { get; set; }
    public int? StudentID { get; set; }


    public Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The best way to handle `null`s is not to use them. The exception in this case is either because the `Reviews` collection is `null` or one of the `Reviews` collection items is `null`. What is the semantical difference between an empty collection and a `null`? What is the meaning of a collection containing an element which is `null`?

Comment: @mjwills, Review.Rating is an Integer.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Jelínek Im thinking if a Review collection item is null it means i has no rating yet.

Comment: @Sefe Good catch! Thank you.

Comment: If `Reviews` is empty, would you expect `AverageRating` to return `null` or 0?

Comment: Why can't `Reviews` be `null` @Sefe? Why would it be NRE? The docs suggest it would be ANE (given it is an extension method). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338413(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mjwills, Im not sure yet if i want it to be null or 0! What would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend `null` since it better reflects "I don't know" rather than "a very low score".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation may do what you need:

```
public double? AverageRating
{
    get
    {
        return Reviews?.Average(x => x?.Rating);
    }
}
```

It will deal with `Reviews` being `null` (it will return `null`), due to use of `?` after `Reviews`.

It will deal with individual `Reviews` being `null` (they will be ignored in terms of calculating the Average), due to use of `?` after `x`.

Comment: This worked! I am now able to see Avg Rating in my view, it is empty which is what i want. I am thinking i will just check if it is null with a ternary and then just have a text like "No rating yet." Thank you for your effort, truly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

### What is null?

First off let's assume that `null` means `unknown`. Eric Lippert's [Null Is Not Empty](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/14/null-is-not-empty/) provides a great reasoning for that. It can be further tracked to the design of SQL and the principles three-state logic. A `null` collection is not empty same as a `null` `int?` is not zero.

But even if you disagree, there are two basic philosophies of working with nulls properly:

### 1. Prevent nulls

Simply adjust your model so that nulls are always prevented during object's lifetime. This is not always possible to achieve through type system (especially when using .NET serialization). This may also lead to a lot of additional boilerplate code at places so use it wisely:

```
public class Model
{
    // is non-null in any Model instance
    public IReadOnlyList<ModelItem> Items { get; }

    public Model(IEnumerable<ModelItem> items)
    {
        Items = new List<ModelItems>(items); // does not check if items contains null
    }
}
```

### 2. Propagate and handle nulls

When you already have a `null`, it's best not to cover up (this hinders maintenance). You can either throw or return `null` up the call stack to other place that is then either forced to handle the `null` or throw.

```
public class ModelItem
{
    public double? Value { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public ICollection<ModelItem> Items { get; set; } // for some reason, e.g. serialization, the Items collection can be null

    public double? Average
    {
        get
        {
            if (Items == null)
            {
                // I don't know what items exist => the average is unknown
                return null;
            }

            return Items.Average(i => i?.Value); // note the ?. here to prevent NullReferenceException
       }
    }
}
```

Note that `Average<Nullable<double>>` doesn't throw `InvalidOperationException` with empty sequence unlike the non-nullable variant, additional check should be added for non-nullable types

Also note that the code is not trying to resolve the `null`s into anything else than other `null`. If your `null` gets handled somewhere, it is most probably a part of your application's business logic and should reside in respective layer (e.g. code that handles backward compatibility with the model of previous version that doesn't have a certain property, returning it as `null`).

However, if your model class inherently assumes that a `null` collection is an empty collection (I would strongly recommend against that for readability and maintenance reasons), the null should indeed not be propagated and should be handled inside that class, e.g. with a coalescing operator (`??`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DefaultIfEmpty` to set `0` value for empty sets and to exclude possible null values from `Average` calculation, you should eliminate them;

```
    public double? AverageRating
    {
        get
        {
            if (Reviews == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Math.Round(Reviews.Where(x => x.Rating.HasValue).Select(x => x.Rating).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average().Value, 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're making use of C# 6.0, you can use null propagation to help specify a default scenario.

The code would end up looking like the following:

```
return Math.Round(Reviews?.Average(c => c.Rating) ?? 0.0, 1);
```

This makes use of null propagation to ensure that the Reviews collection is not Null before accessing the `Average` extension method.

If you have individual items that are NULL, then you can extend the checking inside the lambda as well with the following:

```
return Math.Round(Reviews?.Average(c => c?.Rating ?? 0.0) ?? 0.0, 1);
```

This will guard against Reviews being null or Review's items being null.

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qBTEyf

If you instead need to skip translating NULLs to 0, then you can remove NULL items from the collection with a `Where` statement first.

```
return Math.Round(Reviews?.Where(c => c?.Rating != null).Average(c => c.Rating) ?? 0.0, 1);
```

This way removes any null item from the list before processing it into `Average`.

**EDIT**

Per the comment below, you can use `DefaultIfEmpty` to handle when the sequence itself is empty as below:

```
return Math.Round(Reviews?.DefaultIfEmpty().Average(c => c?.Rating ?? 0.0) ?? 0.0, 1);
```

Calling `DefaultIfEmpty` will return an `IEnumerable` will one null element in it. This will then be filtered out during the `Average` and return 0.

This can also be combined with other methods in this post. The fiddle has been updated with a test example of using `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: Using `return Math.Round(Reviews?.Average(c => c?.Rating ?? 0.0) ?? 0.0, 1);` I am getting `InvalidOperationException: The sequence contains no elements`. My view:  `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AverageRating)`. What could be a possible solution to this issue? I am a bit lost since i am very new to all of this...

Comment: A mistake on my part. `Average` requires a sequence with at least one element for it to process correctly.

The solution would be to check for elements before calling `Average` or use `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: `requires a sequence with at least one element for it to process correctly.` Note that this isn't true for all sequences (e.g. sequence of nullable int).